# How to add a django application in classic asp website in IIS 7.5?

Tags: python, django, asp-classic, iis-7.5

I am currently working on configuring IIS 7.5 where main website is built with classic ASP and need to implement django application INSIDE of main site. I've taken various ways to configure IIS to run django application in classic ASP webpage but for some reason it kept gives `403 Forbidden` error.

I've read and researched articles and posts regarding this issue but most of those resources were about permission issue.

Here are steps / ways I've taken so far.

```
Option 1

1. Add a folder where django application is located as a virtual directory in IIS 7.5
2. Configure DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE, PYTHONPATH, WSGI_HANDLER variables in FastCGI configuration at server level.
3. Add Handler Mapping in application level to run python in IIS.
4. Grant a permission to ASP website's application pool to the django application folder so that ASP website can access django application folder.

Option 2

All of steps are same as option 1 except added django application as a application instead of virtual directory.
```

In terms of application pool, I've tried `DefaultAppPool, IIS_IUSR, IUSR, ApplicationPoolIdentity, NetworkService` but none of them were working. (Btw, whenever I turn on `Directory Browsing`, I can navigate into django application's folder and see contents)

Beside those steps in the above, I've also tried to uncheck `SSL Settings` or at least take a look on other configuration such as `Authentication, .NET Authorization Rules, etc` which allows all users or authenticate users using `Basic Authentication`

I am not sure what's missing here. Any feedbacks ors comments are appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Is the 403 forbidden the ASP/IIS response or the Django 403 response?

Comment: @schillingt it is ASP/IIS response. Basically it shows `403 Forbidden` on blank white screen

Comment: What's the substatus code of 403 error?

Comment: Implementing a python webserver in IIS is quite complicated on its own, even without it being inside classic ASP. You might have a look at [Helicon Zoo](https://www.helicontech.com/zoo/) their product makes it a little easier to run Python webservers under IIS.

Comment: I think you need to make the django folder a separate application, instead of a virtual folder. It will have it's own application pool and you need that to configure the handlers. i think the handler for ASP is now still serving your Python folder.

Comment: @JokiesDing I might not remember correctly but as long as I've found is there were no substatus code of 403 appeared on neither in the console or nor in the screen.

Comment: @ErikOosterwaal I've also tried to make it as an application in IIS and still it failed. I set up a python handler specifically to serve `*.py` files and moved its order to the top, but as soon as moved up to top of the handler list it makes asp application not running, and vice versa. I would look into the Helicon Zoo but highly doubt that it won't solve the issue since it looks like it just helps to implementing python application to run on IIS, not the permission or accessibility. Correct me if I am wrong.